# How to include just caches utility of Guava library in gradle and refuse others?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, guava, android-studio-3.0, google-guava-cache

In Android Studio, I am using CacheBuilder of [Guava library](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki):

```
com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder
```

How to include just this utility?

Comment: copy the files that are needed to your project. also check this https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava

Comment: Consider using the [Caffeine library](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine) instead.

Answer (score 2):

## Use ProGuard

Guava has an entire [wiki section](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/UsingProGuardWithGuava) dedicated to your use case.

If you want to integrate ProGuard with Gradle, just use the following:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        flatDir dirs: '/usr/local/java/proguard/lib'
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath ':proguard:'
    }
}
```

You can find more info on [ProGuard with Gradle here](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/gradle).

Comment: Your mean is that if I use Proguard, it will remove all of those unused libraries. Already I am using it.

Comment: @Patzu It will remove **classes** from **`guava-xx.jar`** that are not needed by your application. So you keep only the classes from Guava you actually use directly or indirectly.